# what is the best choice here was or would

Tags: past-tense

I told you last time not to send them before both **would be**  out or **were** out

Are both sentences idiomatic  I think the second is surer than the first one

Comment: Your cited context is *I **told** you not to do it until they **were** ready*. In the present tense, *I **am telling** you not to do it until they **are** ready*. I can't think of any context where you could use the "hypothetical" form *...until they **would be** ready*.

Comment: ...okay, I found one: [*I put a prescription request for my wife's painkillers on Monday and was told 72 hours **until it would be ready** for pickup.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22until+it+would+be+ready%22) But it doesn't really match your context.

Comment: In your example does it mean that the prescription could take up to 72 hours to be ready and why it is not" until it was ready"

Comment: Strictly speaking, that example should be *...and was told **[that] it would be [up to]** 72 hours until it would be ready for pickup.* Uneducated (or just "careless") native speakers might use Simple Past ***was*** rather than "hypothetical future within the past" ***would be***. Obviously in some contexts the choice between those two would affect the actual meaning: *He said it **was / would** be ready*, for example.

Comment: understand better now

Answer (score 1):

If the first verb is in the past tense, stick with the past tense.

> I **told** you last time not to send them before both **were** out.

The same applies if you use the present tense:

> He says not to send them before both are out.

The use of **would be** would fit after a condition, such as:

> I told you that unless the documents arrived in time, they would be out of date.

(Note: I have amended my answer after misreading your question and noting FumbleFingers' comment.)

Comment: removed the now-irrelevant comment